# How to install or setup j2Objc in android studio steb by step

Tags: android, ios, j2objc

How to use j2objc in android studio?

I did not find any manual. How to implement and work with j2objc in android studio?

I'm a junior in java language, and I wrote one app for android, and now I need convert this app for iOS. It's a simple app.

I want use j2Objc for a separate build app for iOS, but I don't know how to work with j2objc.

Answer (score 0):

Download [distribution](https://developers.google.com/j2objc/guides/getting-started) and this [plugin](https://developers.google.com/j2objc/guides/gradle-plugin). Follow instructions and everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive this obvious question, but you have a Mac, right? You won't be able to build iOS apps without one. That's why many j2objc engineers use Xcode, since UI development and debugging are easier to do there.

Answer (score 0):

I have  win 10 machine.

OK, I downloaded it, unzip, and next step? I dont see any instruction, what i do with this. Paste in specific folder? Implement with plugin wizard? or? Maybe Im stupid, but realy I dont know how these features work on.

I see only:
This package must be built on an OS X system, with: ...

and for gradle plugin ...

oh shit!